# jquery - remove siblings not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle between `font-awesome` elements .

I want to remove the `font-awesome` element when a new `a` tag is clicked. The font-awesome element should be visible only for the current clicked `a` tag.

[FIDDLE][1]

My JS CODE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav ul li:first').append($("<i class='fa fa-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"));
  $('.nav ul li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).append($("<i class='fa fa-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"));
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('fa fa-chevron-right'); // not working
      });

    });
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().siblings().find("i").removeClass('fa fa-chevron-right');`

Comment: @A.J, yes that worked.

Comment: provide a fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you have accepted an answer, but you don't need all that logic - all you have to do is set an active class on the currently selected li - and using CSS add the FA icon to that element. Then clicking each li will remove the active class from the list and then apply it to the selected l=i - and the icon will magically move. Note that I have not applied an event.preventDefault(); to the click of a's - I presume that they should in fact navigate to the element you want - since they are in a nav list.

The benefit of setting the active class to the li - is that you can then style it as you want - as well as adding the icon to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav ul li').click(function(){
    $('nav ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
});
```

```css
nav ul li.active:after {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: "\f054";
   padding-left: 5px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: must be something else in your code - check the snippet - it works fine.

Comment: this is perfect

Comment: thanks - happy to help :) ... note that you can also apply styling to the a within the active li - useful for setting the color of the active li a or changing the fontweight or adding an underline or a CSS trinagle to the ul li as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fontAwesome = $('<i/>').addClass('fa fa-chevron-right');
  $('.nav ul li:first').append(fontAwesome);
  $('.nav ul li a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.nav ul li a i.fa.fa-chevron-right').remove();
    $(this).append(fontAwesome);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section-features">Option A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-functions">Option B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-pecifications">Option C</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```